# Aggregate sales: Showing customers with past, but no current sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Brushing up on some sql... I'm trying to create a list of customers with sales aggregated per year (2005-2008), but will only show customers with sales in previous (2005-2007) yet no sales in 2008.

I've built two queries... not sure which is more effective, but either way I cant seem to figure out how to implement the where clause correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Query 1:

```
select r.ResellerName,
(select sum(rs.SalesAmount) from FactResellerSales rs
where rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
and rs.OrderDateKey >=20050101 and rs.OrderDateKey <20060101) '2005',

(select sum(rs.SalesAmount) from FactResellerSales rs 
where rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
and rs.OrderDateKey >=20060101 and rs.OrderDateKey <20070101) '2006',

(select sum(rs.SalesAmount) from FactResellerSales rs
where rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
and rs.OrderDateKey >=20070101 and rs.OrderDateKey <20080101) '2007',

(select sum(rs.SalesAmount) from FactResellerSales rs
where rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
and rs.OrderDateKey >=20080101 and rs.OrderDateKey <20090101) '2008'

From DimReseller r
order by r.ResellerName ASC
```

Query 2:

```
Select r.ResellerName,
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20050101 and OrderDateKey<20060101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2005',
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20060101 and OrderDateKey<20070101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2006',
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20070101 and OrderDateKey<20080101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2007',
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20080101 and OrderDateKey<20090101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2008'

from DimReseller r
inner join FactResellerSales rs on rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
Group by r.ResellerName
Order by ResellerName ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use query 2 as an inner query and select where 2008 is zero:

```
Select r.ResellerName,
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20050101 and OrderDateKey<20060101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2005',
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20060101 and OrderDateKey<20070101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2006',
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20070101 and OrderDateKey<20080101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2007',
SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20080101 and OrderDateKey<20090101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) '2008'    
from DimReseller r
inner join FactResellerSales rs on rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
Group by r.ResellerName) x
Having SUM(case when OrderDateKey>=20080101 and OrderDateKey<20090101 then rs.SalesAmount else 0 end) = 0
Order by ResellerName ASC
```

The ‘2008' column is always going to be 0, so you don't need it, or it can be replaced with the constant `0`:

```
select
...
0 as '2008'
...
```

if you want.

Comment: '2008' = 0 will always be false. No records will return with this query. You are checking if string '2008' is equal to 0. If you want to do this remove single quotes.

Comment: Jeffrey, thanks for your help, not sure if your query is doing what I wanted (I was reverse engineering it)... but ultimately wanted to show customers that have no sales for 2008, but sales for previous years...

Comment: was it just an issue with using a number for the column heading? Either way it works! thanks so much guys!

Comment: @user3221111 yes - it was about the name of the column and how to refer to a column whose name is a number

Comment: @user3221111 I just realised it can be done a lot easier... see edit!

Comment: @jeffrey although the previous version worked, I totally missed to best solution, which I just realised. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy? Just select the resellerkeys with no Sales in 2008 in a sub select and join these to FactResellerSales?

```
SELECT rs.* 
 FROM FactResellerSales rs
 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT r.ResellerKey
         FROM FactResellerSales
         WHERE OrderDateKey < 20080101) r on rs.ResellerKey = r.ResellerKey
```

UPDATE

```
SELECT r.ResellerName,
       sum(rs.SalesAmount) AS SalesAmount
       YEAR(convert(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),rs.OrderDateKey,101))) AS SALES_YEAR
FROM DimReseller r
INNER JOIN (SELECT rs.SalesAmount,
                   rs.Resellerkey,
                   rs.OrderDateKey
              FROM FactResellerSales rs
              INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.ResellerKey
                            FROM FactResellerSales
            WHERE OrderDateKey < 20080101) a on rs.ResellerKey = a.ResellerKey) sub on r.Resellerkey = sub.Resellerkey
GROUP BY r.ResellerName
ORDER BY r.ResellerName ASC
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding how to integrate that join into my query, would I need to rebuild? Any chance in getting help inserting it? ;)

Comment: See my updated answer. Do not have to time to test. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks again for your help, either way I learned a lot about subqueries by reverse engineering yours!